# Vim colorscheme dynamically change

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is there any way to make the background color for vim dynamic, in which it changes using the brightness, or may be using time hour?

Comment: You can use `strftime()` for that.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of plugins that do this; a simple Internet search brought up these:

- [werewolf](https://github.com/jonstoler/werewolf.vim)
- [sunset](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/sunset)

More details can also be found at [this Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/5y91w9/how_to_change_colorscheme_automatically_depending/).